# Printing from Webview of Expo not working on iOS and Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, expo, react-to-print

I am developing an app that uses react native webview. Inside the webview I am using a website that was built with ReactJS. In the website, I am using react-to-print library to print the contents of the page by component reference. Now, the problem is - when I use expo with webview (inside of which we have that react website) the printing doesn't work.

Expo React native side:

```
<View style={{ width: longDimension, height: shortDimension }}>
  <WebView
    ref={webRef}
    source={{ uri: "http://mywebsite.com/" }}
    webviewDebuggingEnabled={true}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    onLoad={native_to_web}
    onError={errorHandler}
  />
</View>
```

React JS side:

```js
// this doesn't work inside webview
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
  content: () => componentRef.current,
});
//...

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={print}>Print</button>
    <div ref={componentRef}>some content here I want to print</div>
  </div>
);
```

When I tested on iOS device, it shows `Can't open url: about:srcdoc`. On Android nothing happens

What I expect is printing (some popup is opened where you can choose the printer, etc.)